# source code check in / validation best practices

Tags: version-control, code-reviews, source-code

I am looking for best practices that big organizations follow for code check-in and validations.

Currently we follow these steps,
- Developer writes code
- Developer do some initial tests
- Code is awaiting validation now
- Technical lead reviews the code (possible bugs, see if coding convention is followed etc)
- Once approved by technical lead, the code goes in QA state
- Once QA approves the code is checked in into the trunk.

We are now moving to a new project and I was looking for some best practices that would ease the process. We have custom made software that maintains the code status.

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 4):

It seems like bad practice to me that there are no check-ins until the code is production ready. I would have a production branch and only cut over to it when the code has gone through all of those steps. my version of your process would be something like this:

- Developer writes code, checks it in.
- Does initial testing, checks in fixes
- Code gets reviewed, suggested changes (if any) are checked in.
- Reviewed by QA, any changes/fixes here are checked in.
- Code is cut over to the main branch, ready to go run free in the wild.

In your example, it sounds like a check in would only be made once every few days, where checking in is something you should be doing multiple times a day.

Answer (score 0):

The code should always be in source control. The new code can be committed to a branch, reviews, changes, improvements are done there.

QA can be build from the branch.

AFter final approval, merge to trunk.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree that code should be checked in as often as possible, but don't allow check ins that would break the build. Continuous integration is a very good tool to use as well IMO. Requiring all checkins pass the build process and unit tests (and even test coverage if possible) is a good way to ensure that people aren't just throwing stuff over the wall.

Prototypes and other long-running features should go into separate branches as needed and could have less strict rules.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that only a single check in is not very good.  You should check in all the time, unfortunately "Enterprise" VCS seem to make it difficult to check in, which is near-suicide as far as I can tell. Major integration hassles invariably result.

One thing I would add: do a "diff" on the code in version control, and the code about-to-be-checked-in. At the very least, seeing the diff will let you write more cogent check-in comments.  Doing a "diff" before check-in can prevent you from overwriting someone else's changes, or other horrible mistakes.